# How to retain highchart line graph by onClick() function - php mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, highcharts

I have two files
1. Analytics.php
2. get_data_journ.php

**Analytics.php Code**

```
 function show_journal(jour_id){
   $.post("journal_table/get_data_journ.php", {JOURNID: ""+jour_id+""},  function(data_jour){   

        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container_journal',
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false           
            },

             xAxis: {
                 title: {
                    text: 'Year'
                },
                 categories: []
                },

               yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Number of Citations'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },

            series: [{
                type: 'line',
                name: 'Citations',
                data: []

            }]


        }


        $.getJSON("journal_table/get_data_journ.php", {JOURNID:jour_id}, function(data_jour) {
            options.series[0].data = data_jour;

            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });

}); 
}


  echo '<a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #000;" onClick="show_journal('.$jour_id.')">'.$jour_title.'</a>';
```

**get_data_journ.php Code**

```
 <?php
  include '../connect.php';

  $get_journid = $_REQUEST['JOURNID'];

  $result_journ = mysql_query("SELECT year, citations, jour_id FROM journ_graph WHERE  jour_id = '$get_journid'");

  $rows_journ = array();
   while($r_journ = mysql_fetch_array($result_journ)) {
 $row_journ[0] = $r_journ[0];
 $row_journ[1] = $r_journ[1];
 array_push($rows_journ,$row_journ);
 }

 print json_encode($rows_journ, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

 ?>
```

So the onclick function working with while loop, so if have 10 journals, 10 journals will be listed, the user can chose any journal, so according to the user click the line graph will be shown. Here I am using highcharts. This is working very fine. The graph will change accordingly as the user clicks. But now the problem is when users wants to compare the journals like 2 or more, the olp point values should remain in the graph other than disappearing. This onclick event working in the way as per the click, if user clicks another journal then the first journal graph points getting disappeared. How to do that. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created chart, in the second chosing by user, you can use [addSeries](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.addSeries%28%29) which will add serie to the chart, instead of creating new chart.